# Get data from sensor bluetooth le

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing one scholar project using ID-107HR like Heart Rate Sensor. The idea is getting the information of the sensor using one android apps through of the Bluetooth LE.

Actually, my android apps could connect with the ID-107HR sensor, but I don't have idea how can i do for getting the sensor data?.

My apps show me the next information:

```
Device Name: ID107 HR
Device Address: FB:44:E7:74:FB:EB

Services:--------------------------

GAP (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Device Name (00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Appearance (00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters (00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

GATT (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Service Changed (00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

Unknown service (00000af0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Unknown characteristic (00000af6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Unknown characteristic (00000af7-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Unknown characteristic (00000af2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Unknown characteristic (00000af1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

I supose that the third (unknown) service allow to me the get information.

I was reading that this kind of device work like a server, and my android apps act like client.

Thanks for you help....

Answer (score 0):

Standard GATT service UUIDs are defined here
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services

That service and those characteristics aren't part of the standard Heart Rate Profile which you can find out about here:
https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HRP.aspx

Looks like somebody just made-up their own UUID16 numbers rather than using UUID128 as they should have done for a proprietary service. It happens. :-(